# Initializing C struct using pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm working on creating a hash table implementation for an assignment. I've defined my hashtable as struct as follows:

```
typedef struct hashtable {
  int size;
  int entries;
  int table*;   // pointer to table. Each entry will point to linked list 
                // of key-value nodes 
} hashtable;
```

I have to initialize the hashtable struct in a method using double pointers, e.g.:

```
void init(hashtable** ht) {
...
}
```

I've written a basic implementation below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct hashtable {
  int size;
  int entries;
  int table*;   // pointer to table. Each entry will point to linked list 
                // of key-value nodes 
} hashtable;

void init(hashtable**);

void init(hashtable** ht) {
    *ht = (hashtable *) malloc( sizeof(hashtable) );
    *ht->size = 3;
}

int main(){

  hashtable *t = NULL;
  init(&t);

  printf("t.size: %i", t->size);
}
```

However, I keep getting the following compile error:

```
ll.c:19:8: error: member reference base type 'hashtable *' (aka 'struct hashtable *') is not a
      structure or union
    *ht->size = 3;
     ~~^ ~~~~
1 error generated.
```

So I'm confused by the following:
1. I'm not sure how to create a new struct in the init function when being passed a pointer to pointer.
2. After allocating the struct, how do I modify the struct member attributes?

Comment: this `*ht->size = 3;` --> `(*ht)->size = 3;`

Comment: `int table*;`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a operator precedence problem.

The compiler processes -> before the *. Therefore, it tries to access the size member of struct hashtable ** which is not possible.

The code compiles if you exchange *ht->size with (*ht)->size.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 errors in your code :

1. `int table*` --> `int *table` - Declare pointer to integer
2. *ht->size  --> `(*ht)->size`  - Imp to put brackets when you are not sure of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

`->` has higher precedence than `*` in C as you can see from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

using precedence rules `*ht->size` translates  to *(ht->size). That should make clear the reason why you get the error. Another way to see it is

```
*(ht->size)=(*(*ht).size)
```

Fix this using parenthesis as follows: `(*ht)->size`

There is another issue in the definition of `hashtable`:
 `int table*;` won't compile. Use `int *table;` instead to declare a `pointer to int`?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start, and others have addresses the primary issues in your code. However, I would suggest a minor tweak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct hashtable {
  int size;
  int entries;
  int table*;   // pointer to table. Each entry will point to linked list 
                // of key-value nodes 
} hashtable;


// note: freeing the hashtable is a caller responsibility!
hashtable *new_hashtable() {
    hashtable *ht = malloc( sizeof(hashtable) );
    ht->size = 3; // since ht is only a single pointer, no need for (*ht)->foo 

    return ht;
}

int main(){

  hashtable *ht = new_hashtable();

  printf("ht.size: %i", ht->size);

  free(ht);
}
```

Comment: appreciate the feedback on returning the pointer. I'm constrained here by my assignment specifications.

Comment: Oh I see. Well just keep this in mind for the future. This way is safer, because you're never meant to assign `NULL`. You just get the pointer directly from the function, without a chance to forget to call `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the quick response. For future reference, here's a quick update of the original code with solutions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct hashtable {
  int size;     // size of hash table
  int entries;  // number of slots allocated in table
  int *table;   /* pointer to table. Each entry will point to linked list
                  of key-value nodes */
} hashtable;

void init(hashtable**);

void init(hashtable** ht) {
    *ht = (hashtable *) malloc( sizeof(hashtable) );
    (*ht)->entries = 0;
    (*ht)->size = 3; //replace this with better init size, ideally a prime number
    (*ht)->table = malloc( (*ht)->size  * sizeof(int));
}

int main(){

  hashtable *t = NULL;
  init(&t);
  t->table[2] = 3;

  printf("t.size: %i \n", t->size);
  printf("t.arr:[2] %i \n", t->table[2]);
  free(t);
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use `calloc`